# How to Load fragment when the app launches

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have created an app which basically has navigation drawer and I wish to load an fragment "home" whenever the activity launches instead of main activity.
Any idea how to do it.

Comment: Fragments are content of activities, you can't load them instead. You can set them in layouts though https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating#AddInLayout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call this method to view Fragments. In your case call this method on your `onCreate()`

```
//Fragment Changer
    public void changeFragment(Fragment targetfragment) {
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_fragment, targetfragment, "fragment")
                .setTransitionStyle(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }
```

Example Usage

```
 changeFragment(new YourFragment());
```

Answer (score 0):

Basic solution can be implementing something like the below code in your `onCreate` method.

```
// get fragment manager
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

// replace
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.main_layout, new HomeFragment());
ft.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
    }

    public String getHelloMessage() {
        return "Hello!";
    }
}
```

Your View:

```
public class MainView extends Fragment {

    // Declarations
    private Button testButton;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_view, container, false);

        // Getting the reference of controller from Application
        MainController mainController = Application.getInstance().getMainController();

        // Initializing view objects
        testButton = view.findViewById(R.id.test_button);

        // Setting actions
        testButton.setOnClickListener(mainController.getTestAction());

        return view;
    }

    // Reference to the view Object
    public Button getTestButton() {
        return testButton;
    }
```

Your main_activity.xm lto connect the fragment

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/containerMainView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mainView"
        android:name="com.template.views.MainView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Your main_view.xml file your final view definition

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/test_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="@string/say_hello" />
</RelativeLayout>
```